# How to create a toggle/switch button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to add a `toggel`/`switch` button in Flutter but so far haven't found the desired result. I'm creating the `layout` for an `APP` as it's in the attached screenshot but stuck on the `toggle`/`switch` button part which will switch the language of the `APP`.

[image]

Comment: There is a flutter package available at `pub.dev` named `toggle_switch` which might not be much close to what you asked but perform same functionality here is the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch)

Comment: You can use this [link] (https://github.com/shubhamhackz/light_dark_toggle) for the same design without using any package.

Comment: @MarufHassan I have made the Changes to implement the design he wanted.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's how you can implement the toggle design you wanted :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AnimatedToggle extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> values;
  final ValueChanged onToggleCallback;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color buttonColor;
  final Color textColor;

  AnimatedToggle({
    @required this.values,
    @required this.onToggleCallback,
    this.backgroundColor = const Color(0xFFe7e7e8),
    this.buttonColor = const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    this.textColor = const Color(0xFF000000),
  });
  @override
  _AnimatedToggleState createState() => _AnimatedToggleState();
}

class _AnimatedToggleState extends State<AnimatedToggle> {
  bool initialPosition = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: Get.width * 0.6,
      height: Get.width * 0.13,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              initialPosition = !initialPosition;
              var index = 0;
              if (!initialPosition) {
                index = 1;
              }
              widget.onToggleCallback(index);
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Container(
              width: Get.width * 0.6,
              height: Get.width * 0.13,
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: widget.backgroundColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Get.width * 0.1),
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: List.generate(
                  widget.values.length,
                  (index) => Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Get.width * 0.05),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.values[index],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Rubik',
                        fontSize: Get.width * 0.045,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: const Color(0xAA000000),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedAlign(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            curve: Curves.decelerate,
            alignment:
                initialPosition ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Container(
              width: Get.width * 0.33,
              height: Get.width * 0.13,
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: widget.buttonColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Get.width * 0.1),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                initialPosition ? widget.values[0] : widget.values[1],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Rubik',
                  fontSize: Get.width * 0.045,
                  color: widget.textColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using our `AnimatedToggle` :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:playground/animated_toggle.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Toggle Button'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _toggleValue = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Toggle Button'),
        elevation: 10,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            AnimatedToggle(
              values: ['English', 'Arabic'],
              onToggleCallback: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _toggleValue = value;
                });
              },
              buttonColor: const Color(0xFF0A3157),
              backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFB5C1CC),
              textColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
            ),
            Text('Toggle Value : $_toggleValue'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Shubhamhackz  Where find  animated_toggle.dart

Comment: thanks for sharing this code

Comment: what is the yaml install for import 'package:playground/animated_toggle.dart';

Comment: @GoldenLion This file's contents are posted by Shubham in the first part of the code.. Just paste it in another file and import that file in the second file.

Comment: @GoldenLion For now you can copy-paste the code, I'll create a package around this shortly.